# I was trying to build a merge sort but ending up with an error

Tags: sorting, merge

The method `mergeSort(int[])` is undefined for the type merge. This is the error that I am facing. Can anyone please point out my fault? Might be I'm making a syntax error, please point out the mistake im making.

```
public class merge {
    public static mergeSort(int[] a) {
        int n = a.length;
        if (n < 2) {
            return(a[]);
        }
        int mid = n / 2;
        int left[] = new int[mid];
        int left[] = new int[n - mid];

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            left[i] = a[i];
        }

        for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
            right[i - mid] = a[i];
        }

        mergeSort(left[]);
        mergeSort(right[]);
        mmerge(left[], right[], A);
    }

    public static void mmerge(int[] l, int[] r, int[] array) {
        int len1 = l.length();
        int len2 = r.length();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while (i < len1 && j < len2) {
            if (l[i] <= r[j]) {
                array[k]=l[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            } else {
                array[k] = r[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        while (i < len1) {
            array[k] = l[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        while (j < len2) {
            array[k] = r[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = { 4, 6, 2, 9, 1, 7, 3 };
        mergeSort(arr);

        for (int p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
            System.out.print(arr[p]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps to do a search for your specific error, the first issue is that the mergesort function doesn't have a return value.  Since this is setup to be void, the return command from mergesort shouldn't have any value (second issue).  Then the subsequent mergesort calls are type mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class merge {
    public static void mergeSort(int[] a) {
        int n=a.length;
        if(n<2) {
            return;
        }
        int mid=n/2;
        int left[]=new int[mid];
        int right[]=new int[n-mid];

        for (int i=0;i<mid;i++) {
            left[i]=a[i];
        }

        for (int i=mid;i<n;i++) {
            right[i-mid]=a[i];
        }

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        mmerge(left,right,a);
    }

    public static void mmerge(int[] l,int[] r,int[] array) {
        int len1=l.length;
        int len2=r.length;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        while(i<len1 && j<len2) {
            if(l[i]<=r[j]) {
                array[k]=l[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }else {
                array[k]=r[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(i<len1) {
            array[k]=l[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        while(j<len2) {
            array[k]=r[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] arr={4,6,2,9,1,7,3};
        mergeSort(arr);

        for(int p=0;p<arr.length;p++) {
            System.out.print(arr[p]+" ");
        }

    }
}
```